# Mysql - Adding Records

Tags: mysql

If two individual records are added to a database such as two patients being added to the table 'Paitents' and when they are added the Primary_Key such as Paitient_ID is created automatically and given to each new account.
.(Auto Incremented)
That bit is quite straight forward and understand I can just use an 'INSERT INTO SONGS' statement.
But what if the two patients are related and I have another table called "Relations"
Where by I need it to pull in the two Paitent_ID's and create a relation from the same insert query. Can this be done?

Comment: Yes. You would need to insert into that table in the same way, as your database cannot automatically know when people are related

Comment: How are you adding the patients? One-by-one in a form, POSTing the form for each patient? Or do you have a form on which more than one patient can be entered, and then the details of both posted together in one POST?

Answer (score 1):

ID generated by MySQL automatically in `auto_increment` column can be obtained using the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` function. Languages/libraries often offer a function for this (e.g. in PHP PDO you call `PDO::lastInsertId()` instead of making another query).

How to solve this exactly depends on how you are inserting the values into a database, but the basics can be:

1. Insert patient one
2. Get the ID
3. Insert patient two
4. Get the ID
5. Create the relation

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. At the stage I am just working purely in Mysql and not using GUI for the frontend. Just trying to get my head around what I can or can not do . Is it possible to use the LAST_INSERT_ID() in Mysql ? How would this query look?

Comment: Sure thing! You can simply use `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`. If you're working in MySQL only, I guess it would be best to use variables, like so: after first Patient insert, you `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @patientOne`, after second insert, you `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @patientTwo`, and then just `INSERT INTO Relation VALUES @patientOne, @patientTwo`.